Install Abaqus 2021 on Rocky Linux 8.10
I'm trying to install Abaqus 2021 on a Rocky Linux system (currently version 8.10). To be able to launch the installation script "StartTUI.sh" I modified all "Linux.sh"-files and changed:
< DSY_OS_Release=`lsb_release --short --id |sed 's/ //g'`
---
> DSY_OS_Release="CentOS"

This procedure worked find with Abaqus 2022, but unfortunately version 2021 will stop continuing at "Running verification.". Prior step from the installer is:
Generating file /opt/abaqus/2021/InstallData/log/20240816T084918+0200_CODE_linux_a64_SIMULIA_EstPrd.media/tmp/verifyWrapper.sh
Launching application ...
Running chmod -755 over installed files  ...
Running verification.

The contents of "verifyWrapper.sh" are:
cd /opt/abaqus/2021/InstallData/log/20240816T084918+0200_CODE_linux_a64_SIMULIA_EstPrd.media/tmp
"/opt/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/ABQLauncher" verify -install -log 

So I tried launching the verification with other parameters:
/opt/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/ABQLauncher verify -install -verbose

This is the output that stops eventually without any progress:
Abaqus Product Install Verification...

Fri Aug 16 09:27:59 2024

WARNING: Unable to determine if Fortran Compiler is present.

Found /misc/software/abaqus/2021/AM_SIM_Abaqus_Extend.AllOS/1/verify.  All
verification files will reside in this directory.

Old job files exist.  They will be moved to verifyOLD.

Status of installation components:

   standard is installed
   explicit is installed
   cae is installed
   tosca is not installed
   odb is installed
   caa is installed

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Abaqus/Standard parametric studies


   Abaqus/Standard parametric studies is supported on this platform
   (lnx86_64).

   Abaqus/Standard parametric studies is licensed.

   Executing...
   "/cluster/application/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/SMALauncher" fetch -
   job studyQA_std.inp > studyQA_std.fetch 2>&1

   Executing...
   "/cluster/application/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/SMALauncher" fetch -
   job studyQA_std.psf >> studyQA_std.fetch 2>&1

   Executing...
   "/cluster/application/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/SMALauncher" fetch -
   job studyQA_std.psr >> studyQA_std.fetch 2>&1

   Executing...
   "/cluster/application/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/SMALauncher"
   script=studyQA_std > studyQA_std.log 2>&1


These are the contents of the last logfile:
$ cat /misc/software/abaqus/2021/AM_SIM_Abaqus_Extend.AllOS/1/verify/studyQA_std.log 
Run /cluster/application/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/eliT_SiteID
Run /cluster/application/abaqus/2021/linux_a64/code/bin/eliT_SiteID
 ***COMMENT: Starting execution of all designs of the parameter study:


Any ideas on what to do next to be able to install and verify abaqus 2021 on rocky linux (or probably any RHEL 8) successfully?
